# Weird results when playing with DQN with targets

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I've been trying to implement DQN with a target network and I'm getting some really weird results.

When I try to train my DQN from scratch on Cartpole, it doesn't seem to learn and loss increases in an exponential fashion.

However, if I load in a pretrained model trained without the use of a target network, the model works very well, outperforming the continued training of the tradition DQN.

Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what the problem is?

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 16)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(32, 32)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(32, output_dim)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear3(x))
        return self.linear4(x)


final_epsilon = 0.05
initial_epsilon = 1
epsilon_decay = 5000
global steps_done
steps_done = 0


def select_action(state):
    global steps_done
    sample = random.random()
    eps_threshold = final_epsilon + (initial_epsilon - final_epsilon) * \
                    math.exp(-1. * steps_done / epsilon_decay)
    if sample > eps_threshold:
        with torch.no_grad():
            state = torch.Tensor(state)
            steps_done += 1
            q_calc = model(state)
            node_activated = int(torch.argmax(q_calc))
            return node_activated
    else:
        node_activated = random.randint(0,1)
        steps_done += 1
        return node_activated


class ReplayMemory(object): # Stores [state, reward, action, next_state, done]

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = [[],[],[],[],[]]

    def push(self, data):
        """Saves a transition."""
        for idx, point in enumerate(data):
            #print("Col {} appended {}".format(idx, point))
            self.memory[idx].append(point)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        rows = random.sample(range(0, len(self.memory[0])), batch_size)
        experiences = [[],[],[],[],[]]
        for row in rows:
            for col in range(5):
                experiences[col].append(self.memory[col][row])
        return experiences

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory[0])


input_dim, output_dim = 4, 2
model = DQN(input_dim, output_dim)
target_net = DQN(input_dim, output_dim)
target_net.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
target_net.eval()
tau = 1
discount = 0.99

learning_rate = 1e-4
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

memory = ReplayMemory(65536)
BATCH_SIZE = 128


def optimize_model():
    if len(memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
        return 0
    experiences = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
    state_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[0])
    action_batch = torch.LongTensor(experiences[1]).unsqueeze(1)
    reward_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[2])
    next_state_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[3])
    done_batch = experiences[4]

    pred_q = model(state_batch).gather(1, action_batch)

    next_state_q_vals = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE)

    for idx, next_state in enumerate(next_state_batch):
        if done_batch[idx] == True:
            next_state_q_vals[idx] = -1
        else:
            # .max in pytorch returns (values, idx), we only want vals
            next_state_q_vals[idx] = ((target_net(next_state_batch[idx]).max(0)[0]).detach())

    better_pred = (reward_batch + next_state_q_vals).unsqueeze(1)

    loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(pred_q, better_pred)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.grad.data.clamp_(-1, 1)
    optimizer.step()
    return loss


env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
for i_episode in range(300):
    model.train()
    target_net.eval()
    observation = env.reset()
    episode_loss = 0
    if i_episode % tau == 0:
        target_net.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
    for t in range(200):
        #env.render()
        state = observation
        action = select_action(observation)
        observation, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

        if done:
            next_state = [0,0,0,0]
        else:
            next_state = observation

        memory.push([state, action, reward, next_state, done])
        optimize_model()
        if done:
            print("Episode {} finished after {} timesteps".format(i_episode, t+1))
            break
env.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the update frequency of the target network. I've modified your tau value to 100, and it solves the Cartpole problem. The answer to your question is the original design of the DQN architecture in 2013 didn't contain the target network. Without the target network, each time a parameter update causes the next iteration to have higher Q value and make the training to be unstable. So keeping an older set of parameters stabilises the training process. However, you must keep the older set of parameters old enough to be a target for the main model to optimise to. Also, you have to keep it updated to prevent fixed target model from causing overfit to the old set of parameters which learns nothing from the environment.

loss value:

`tau=2`

[image]

`tau=100`

[image]

`tau=1000`

[image]

Result of `tau=100`:

[image]